# unable to locate package ros-iron-desktop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ros2, i first installed ros2 foxy but had some issues with gazebo bridge package and also as ros2 foxy went to end of life i decided to try ros2 iron and now during installing it through provided documentation, during installing ros-iron-desktop its ts showing me error that  ""Unable to locate package ros-iron-desktop""
Please help me with it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418062/unable-to-locate-package-ros-iron-desktop/) by [Brijrajsinh Raolji](https://answers.ros.org/users/168023/brijrajsinh-raolji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2023-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-08-03**:
Can you confirm you are running a supported OS? Iron only supports Ubuntu `22.04` (or *Jammy*).

I ask because Foxy can't be installed on `22.04`, so if you didn't upgrade your OS, it would be expected to not be able to install Iron.

**Comment by [Brijrajsinh Raolji](https://answers.ros.org/users/168023/brijrajsinh-raolji/) on 2023-08-06**:
Yes that was the issue, I figured it out thanks for addressing though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured it out, as iron only works on 22.04 I was not able to install that.

---

Originally posted by [Brijrajsinh Raolji](https://answers.ros.org/users/168023/brijrajsinh-raolji/) with karma: 16 on 2023-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0